# Python: Unicode characters in file or folder names

Tags: python, unicode, path

We process a lot of files where path can contain an extended character set like this:
F:\Site Section\Cieślik

My Python scripts fail to open such files or chdir to such folders whatever I try.

Here is an extract from my code:

```
import zipfile36 as zipfile
import os
from pathlib import Path

outfile = open("F:/zip_pdf3.log", "w", encoding="utf-8")
with open('F:/zip_pdf.txt') as f:   # Input file list - note the forward slashes!
    for line in f:
    
    print (line)  
    path, filename =  os.path.split(line)
    file_no_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(line))[0]
    
    try:
      os.chdir(path)     # Go to the file path
    except Exception as exception:
             print (exception, file = outfile)   #3.7
             print (exception)
             continue
```

I tried the following:

1. Converting path to a raw string

   ```
    raw_string = r"{}".format(path)
    try:
      os.chdir(raw_string)
   ```
2. Converting a string to Path

   Ppath = Path(path)

   ```
    try:
      os.chdir(Ppath.decode("utf8"))
   ```

Out of ideas... Anyone knows how to work with Unicode file and folder names? Using Python 3.7 or higher on Windows.

Could be as simple as that - thanks @SergeBallesta:

```
with open('F:/pdf_err.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

I may post updates after more runs with different input.
This, however, leads to a slightly different question: if, instead of reading from the file, I walk over folders and files with extended character set - how do I deal with those, i.e.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir): ?
```

At present I'm getting either a "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" or "Can't open the file".

Comment: The problem is likely to be in the encoding of the 'F:/zip_pdf.txt' file. Windows gladly accept Unicode and spaces in file and folder names, and Python 3 easily processes Unicode characters, but a text file only contains **bytes**, so you must tell `open` what encoding to use.

Comment: Usual warning. You are in Windows, do not trust "print" output. On Windows often you do not get UTF-8 output (as you find in all other modern operating systems).

Comment: FYI, you can't "format" a raw string.  A raw string can only be written in source code as a string literal.  `raw_string = r"{}".format(path)` is the same as `raw_string = raw_string`.

Comment: `os.walk()` reads Unicode filenames fine.  Are you joining the subdir with the file?  Plenty of examples already on SO, but make a new SO question with a [mcve] if you still have issues.