# Python: Unicode characters in file or folder names - os.walk and magic

Tags: python, windows, unicode, os.walk

I was advised to ask a new question linked to [Python: Unicode characters in file or folder names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70665877/python-unicode-characters-in-file-or-folder-names).

The former was about reading the path from the list, this one is about walking through folders and subfolders.

Below is the extract from the code. It walks through the folders and prints some information about the files into the output, which can be later imported into Excel.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import magic
import traceback

filepath = open('F:/filepath.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')

rootdir = "F:"

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if len(files)>0:
        l = len(files)
        
        print(subdir + os.sep + '>>>'+ str(l))    # folder (if not empty) and number of files in it
    f = subdir + os.sep + ">>>>" + str(len(files))

    for file in files:
      try:  
        ff = subdir + os.sep + file
        ff = os.path.abspath(ff)  # workaround MAX_PATH
        ff = u"\\\\?\\" + ff      # workaround MAX_PATH
        file_size = os.path.getsize(ff)/1000000
        file_no_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
        file_type=magic.from_file(ff)
        filepath.writelines(ff + ">>>>" + file + ">>>>" + file_no_ext + ">>>>" + os.path.splitext(file)[1] + ">>>>" + str(file_size) + ">>>>" + file_type + '\n')
    # Filepath Filename Extension Size
      except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        continue  
          
filepath.close()
```

On files with extended character set in their name magic throws an exception like: "cannot open `\?\F:\Csom\303\263s\23-Dec-2020.pdf' (No such file or directory)". At the same time file path is written out as "\?\F:\CsomÃ³s\23-Dec-2020.pdf".

Q1: How to ensure magic can open the file and return its type?

Q2: How to output the file/folder name exactly as it appears?

I believe MAX_PATH has been redefined in all environments, but not bothered about leading "\?".

I am on Windows 10 and my file system is NTFS.

Comment: Looks like you are on Windows. If you can't simply move to something less flaky, perhaps [edit] your question to specify details about the OS and the file system's configuration (code page, etc).

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?  Also how are you viewing the file with the paths?  `CsomÃ³s` is a UTF-8 file viewed as (likely) Windows-1252, so the file is written correctly but the tool used to view the file is using the US Windows default code page.  Many Windows editors like UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding to correctly display a UTF-8 file, so try writing the file with `'utf-8-sig'` instead.

Comment: Q2 seems to have an  answer. The change is: ff_utf = str(ff.encode('utf-8'),'utf-8') and use this in writelines instead of ff. However, even with this filename magic still can't open it (Q1). I'm using Python 3, but different machines have different versions installed.